# Bootstrap navbar spacing on right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my bootstrap web app, on the navigation bar header, there is no space on the right hand side. And the logout link is very close to the right border.

How can I give some space on the right ?

**Image:**

[image]

**index.html**

```
    <!-- Start of Navigation Menu -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="listController">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#/list">My Project</a>


        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <div class="bgContainer" style="background-image: url('images/bg_header.gif');">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#/list"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></i>List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/two"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i> Two</a></li>


                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Calendar <b
                            class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                            <li><a href="#/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View Submission </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View Submission </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> Report  </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Template  - </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>  Calendar</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>Generate 
                            </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>   Report </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>  Draft  </a></li>
                                </ul></li>
                            <li><a href="#/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>  Feedback</a></li>
                        </ul></li>




                    <li><a href="dashboard"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                </ul>


                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                {{fullName}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul id="g-account-menu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#/underConstruction">My Profile</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                        <li><a href="#/underConstruction"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Logout </a></li>
                        <!-- Spacer -->
                        <li>     </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Navigation Menu -->
```

Comment: ul.navbar-nav li:last-child {margin-right:15px;}

Comment: Any custom CSS? a runnable example would really help

Comment: can you please provide fiddle or snippet?

Comment: Possibly throw a container div around the navbar, or even just a row div would give you a bit of extra spacing to that end.

Comment: It should be in a `container` or `container-fluid` http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: With `navbar-fixed-top` you would need to pair it with `container-fluid`. [Here's a Fiddle showing how it works](https://jsfiddle.net/3pmq6utn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by `.navbar-right` class due to positioning or overflow issues with navbar container.

Default bootstrap rule:

```
.navbar-right {
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Override it with:

```
.navbar-right {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this gives some spacing on the right. Why they gave -15px as default ? That's strange.

Comment: Because the navbar should be in a `container` or `container-fluid`, then you wouldn't need the extra css override.

Comment: @Jay Well, I guess this is just a layout consistency concern. `.container` and `.container-fluid` classes have `margin-left: 15px;` and `margin-right: 15px;`. Bootstrap `.row` class has `margin-left: -15px;` and `margin-right: -15px;`, so if you put `.row` inside a `.container` you will end up with a row, that completely fills container. But you don't usually put `.navbar` into `.row` element, so you don't get that `-15px` for consistency. However, there is `.navbar-brand` class, that has `margin-left: -15px;` and `.navbar-right` class, which has `margin-right: -15px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

I just added a white space to the last menu item using

```
<li><a href="#/underConstruction"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Logout &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>
```

Comment: This is probably the worst way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. But if I include container-fluid as you suggested the header section and the body section does not align properly in width and both had different width.